# Делаем так, чтобы основная прога заработала после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, selenium

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

from arizona import *

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

import time

url_main = 'http://forum.arizona-rp.com/index.php?online/&type=registered' # Адрес форума



class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Флудилка для Аризоны")
        # События кнопок Авторизации И Регистрации
        self.ui.floodbutton.clicked.connect(self.Floodbutton)
        # Поля с ником и паролём
        self.ui.nick.textChanged[str].connect(self.Nick)
        self.ui.password.textChanged[str].connect(self.Password)

    def Floodbutton(self):
        pass

    def Nick(self, nick):
        pass

    def Password(self, password):
        pass



def parse_fist_list_user(driver, url):

    url_list_users = []
    driver.get(url)
    # Обход проверки браузера
    time.sleep(10)

    # Получаем блок навигации
    div_PageNav = driver.find_element_by_class_name('PageNav')

    #Получаем количество страниц
    count_page = int(div_PageNav.get_attribute('data-last'))
    #Заполняем список url страниц с пользователями
    for i in range(1,count_page):
        url_list_users.append(url_main+'&page='+str(i))
        print(url+'&page='+str(i))
    return url_list_users


def parse_list_users(driver,urls):
    users_url = []
    #Переход по очереди
    for url in urls:

        driver.get(url)
        print('Страница:', url)

        users = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.memberListItem')
        for user in users:
            users_url.append(user.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href'))

    return users_url

# Логинимся

def login(driver):
    logbutton = driver.find_element_by_id('loginBarHandle')
    logbutton.click()

    time.sleep(3)

    loginarea = driver.find_element_by_id('LoginControl')
    loginarea.send_keys('BNTZ')

    passwordarea = driver.find_element_by_id('ctrl_password')
    passwordarea.send_keys('max777')


    buttonlog_xpath = '//input[@type="submit" and @value="Вход"]'
    buttonlog = driver.find_element_by_xpath(buttonlog_xpath)
    buttonlog.click()


# Гоняем по аккаунтам и спамим
def check_users(driver):
    usercount = 0
    for x in users:
        driver.get(x)
        rang = driver.find_element_by_class_name('userBanners')
        # Проверка на группу
        if rang.text == "Пользователь":
            message = driver.find_element_by_name('message')
            message.send_keys('https://vk.com/samp_portland')

            NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//input[@type="submit" and @value="Отправить"]'
            button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
            button.click()

            usercount += 1

            time.sleep(30)

            print(usercount)

        else:
            print('-')

def init_driver():
    binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
    profile = FirefoxProfile()  # если запускаетесь с дефолтным, то можно пропустить
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\spammer\\geckodriver.exe")
    return driver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    driver = init_driver()
    url_list_users = parse_fist_list_user(driver, url_main)
    users = parse_list_users(driver, url_list_users)
    for user in users:
        print(user)
    print('Количество пользователей онлайн:',str(len(users)))
    print('Время парсинга:',time.time()-start)
    login = login(driver)
    check = check_users(driver)




# DEBUG
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    sys.exit(1)

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

Как сделать так, чтобы браузер (начинала выполняться остальная часть кода) открывался после нажатия на кнопку(Активации функции Floodbutton)

Answer (score 0):

В той же директории можно создать файл с кодом, в котором есть функция, в которой происходит открытие браузера, его работа и тд. А в функции, которую вы привязали к нажатию на кнопку вписать <имя файла без расширения>.<имя нужной функции из созданного файла>() В начале вашего файла импортировать созданный файл

То есть создать файл example.py с функцией func, которая запускает нужный процесс, а в функции, которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку в исходном файле, прописать example.func() И вначале файла импортировать нужный файл - import example
В итоге функция, привязанная к нажатию на кнопку, будет выполнять код, расположенный в файле example.py
Нужно также учитывать, что пока не выполнится код из файла? работа основной программы будет приостановлена, любой графический интерфейс там зависнет до окончания выполнения example.py Решить это возможно с помощью многопоточности - почитайте про библиотеку threading.

Предложенный способ может не очень, но можно попробовать реализовать это

Comment: К сожалению такой ответ не подошёл

Comment: Почему? Можно же нужную часть кода в функцию положить и вызывать когда нужно. А почему не подошло-то? Может всё-таки смогу как-то помочь